# How to check if a function does anything?

Tags: javascript, function

Let's say we have the following functions:

```
function a() {}
function b() {
  console.log("Hello World!");
}
```

Now let's use a (non-existent) function called `does_anything` that returns a boolean, which lets you know if the specified function has any statements/expressions in it:

```
does_anything(a); // false
does_anything(b); // true
```

How would you implement such a function?

Comment: The first step will be to convert function to string.

Comment: What would be the utility of such a function?

Comment: What should the output be for a function with a statement that has no side-effects, I.E. `function foo ( ) { "bar" }`

Comment: @ScottHunter To be honest, I'm just curious. I personally don't think such a function would be of any use. You'd be wasting memory trying to determine if a function was empty.